# How is spanish accented character displayed for spanish keyboard?

Tags: character, special-characters, keycode

I have an English keyboard. With little setting on keyboard preferences on my window machine I am able to type Spanish character.

---

To type **á** I have to press two keys. 
**'** + **a** = **á**
But when I change to normal English layout I get
**'** + **a** = **'a**

How is switching between different keyboard/layout gives different result?  As per my understandng in both the cases it passes the same keycode but the end results are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not give the same result, since they are different symbols.

- "Spanish" accent, aso known as "acute accent" has its own utf-8 code and it is used to change the sound-values of the letters to which they are added.
- The other symbols is an apostrophe, whose use is quite different to previous one.

That's because I believe there are some reasons to think that they are not using the same keycode but it's using a different keys configuration.

Take a look at this UTF-8 table:
https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl

- Accent: U+00B4
- Apostrophe: U+0027

Please, review your keyboard to ensure it is correctly configured to differentiate both symbols.

In my case, with spanish keyboard configuration, I'm able to display both as follows:

- Soy Rubén (spanish example)
- I'm Rubén (english translation)

Comment: My mistake. Thanks @rubengnzalez for pointing out the difference. I wasn't aware of "acute accent". This make sense on how the convertion is taking place.

Comment: No problem! Cheers